# Как отловить удаление приложения android?

Tags: android, app

Хочу сделать проверку на удаление приложения пользователем. Нашел этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled). Там в манифесте нужно указать строку:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

но эта строка уже считается deprecated, и у меня собственно вопрос - стоит ли дожать этот вопрос и сделать все как там написано, или есть какой-то более новый и свежий способ? Для чего я это хочу сделать - после удаления приложения на устройстве остаются разные файлы видимые и не видимые пользоватею, и я хочу их как-то удалить. Я так понял это можно сделать только через отлов удаления.

Comment: Размещайте файлы, которые должны быть удалены, в приватных папках приложения (это которые получают через контекст) - они автоматически удаляются вместе с приложением.

Comment: что это за папки - приватные? типа те что в data находятся туда куда без рута не долезешь? я просто хочу кроме того что удалять файлы, чистить sharedpreferences, а это не получается сделать нормально

Comment: Да, направление верное, только к собственным файлам рут не нужен. Преференсы хранятся там же в виде xml-файлов и тоже удаляются вместе с приложением. Кроме того, папки полученные через `Context.getExternal...` создаются на SDCard по пути `Android/data/package.name/` и доступны всем без рута, но опять же удаляются вместе с приложением.

Comment: то есть файлы, например фото юзера, тоже писать по пути `Android/data/package.name/` и они будут стираться при удалении?

Comment: И при удалении приложения и при очистке данных! через настройки. То есть надо определиться, что должно удаляться, а что нет. Очистку данных через настройки можно переопределить собственной активностью (не помню, правда, с каким фильтром её нужно объявить) - то есть Вы можете контролировать, что будет можно очистить, а что нет.

Comment: @woesss, теперь я запутался, что значит `контролировать что будет можно удалить, а что нет`?? я вот зашел в папку `Android/data/` и не вижу папки package_name, получается после удаления приложения я хочу удалять файлы которые я сохранил в отдельную папку созданную для приложения и префы тоже, префов я не увидел

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93292/discussion-between-woesss-and-andrew-goroshko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размещайте файлы, которые должны быть удалены, в приватных папках приложения (это которые получают через контекст) - они автоматически удаляются вместе с приложением.

Преференсы хранятся там же в виде xml-файлов и тоже удаляются вместе с приложением. Кроме того, папки полученные через `Context.getExternal...` создаются на SDCard по пути `Android/data/package.name/` и доступны всем без рута, но опять же удаляются вместе с приложением.

Так же все эти файлы удаляются при очистке данных приложения через системное меню
"О приложении", но эту очистку можно переопределить собственной активностью (не помню, правда, с каким фильтром её нужно объявить) - то есть Вы можете контролировать, что будет можно очистить, а что нет.  Но при удалении самого приложения эта активность не будет вызвана и будут удалены все приватные файлы.

Comment: вот все почти понял, но так и не понял что за приватные папки, как к ним получить доступ? Я нашел такое - `ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()`, вы этот контекст имели в виду?

Comment: Любой наследник контекста - любая Ваша активити наследует эти методы. В этом руководстве немножко написано про хранение  файлов: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html