# Удалить каталог вместе с приложением

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня создается папка MyLocs с подпапками и `тхт` файлами при установки приложения по пути `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()...` Как сделать, чтобы папка `MyLocs`(со всем содержимым) удалялась вместе с приложением?

Answer (score 1):

Если создавать папку не через `Environment`, а через `Context`, то она будет автоматически удаляться вместе с приложением. Но, это подойдёт только для папок, которые используются приложением в "технических" целях.

Во всех остальных случаях всё-таки лучше `Environment` и, как неизбежность, удаление руками.

Comment: У меня пользователь будет иконки добавлять свои, поэтому и сделано Environment, там же хранятся и фотки и конфиги. Но ведь тогда надо в описании приложения писать, что эту папку надо удалять вручную? Я просто подумал, а все ли это прочитают и всем ли это понравится, а то потом плохих отзывов еще наставят на гугл плей, что мусор остается после удаления приложения)

Comment: "Добавлялку" значков и пр. можно сделать в самом приложении. В крайнем случае через `Context` доступна папка `Android` (кто подключал гаджет к компу, видел её не один раз). Пользовательские значки и пр. сохранять там. При удалении приложения подпапка приложения в `Android` также удалится сама.

Comment: По задумке, в этой папке хранятся точки с фотографиями, фотки весят иногда по 5 мб, то есть эта папка MyLocs со всем содержимым потенциально будет весить гигабайты.. И ее надо как-то копировать, чтобы делать бекап и возможность переносить на другое устройство, чтобы потом программа подхватывала все это.. Вот и не знаю как лучше, пока все для ручного пользования сделано через Environment, может посоветуете что.. Копировать папку в несколько гигабайт для бекапа тоже ведь не камильфо, особенно во внутреннем хранилище..

Comment: Через контекст можно получить путь к папке во внешней памяти, но созданной специально для вашего приложения и удаляющейся вместе с ним. Посмотрите ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/978584/11515, может станет понятнее